# Could we orphanize [adoption]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[adoption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adoption) has 17 questions, no tag wiki, 0 followers and questions mainly about adopting a certain technology (or how the companies use some technology).

What do you think?

Comment: I think most of these questions should be closed as primarily opinion-based. Going to work...

Comment: Only 5 left open now.

Comment: Does orphanize mean removing the parents, or killing them? O_o

Comment: All [tag:adoption] questions [on hold]/[closed] now.